# Use ILIKE in sequelize where clause(JSON column)

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have JSON column where I have stored data like -

```
{ tag : ["as","bs","cs"] }
```

I want to search within this column with `ILIKE` and I believe JSON datatype is just string so I used query like -

```
SELECT * FROM public."Transactions" WHERE tags::text ILIKE '%as%'
```

above query works fine in sql

I need to implement this with sequelize model **with no success
code** I used is

```
    let searchQuery = [
        {
            payee: {
                [Op.iLike]: '%' + search + '%'
            }
        },
        {
            tags: {
                [Op.iLike]: '%as%'
            }
        }
    ];
```

***gives error as***

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist:
>   json ~~* unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

check the list of operators - there's no `~~` - `ILIKE` does not work with json. You have to either cast json to text:

```
t=# select '{ "tag" : ["as","bs","cs"] }'::json::text ilike '%as%';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

or use native operator:

```
t=# select ('{ "tag" : ["as","bs","cs"] }'::json)->'tag'->>0 = 'as';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

or if you are 9.5 and above - cast to jsonb and use its powerful operators:

```
t=# select '{ "tag" : ["as","bs","cs"] }'::json::jsonb @> '{"tag":["as"]}'::jsonb;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html